# Wordpress Gutenberg InnerBlock.Content is not being saved or rendered

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am creating a custom block in Gutenberg via custom plugin. My custom block contains InnerBlocks. The edit function appears to be working correctly, as I can add the block to the page, and place new block elements inside the block as intended. The issue arrises when I reload the page. After I update the page and reload the editor, all of the InnerBlock elements are gone. They are not being saved, and not being rendered on the frontend either. Unless I'm crazy, my save function is not built correctly. Any help would be great. I am well versed in Wordpress and JS, but new to React and Gutenberg. Thanks for any help!

```
( function( blocks, element, editor ) {

    const el = element.createElement;
    const { registerBlockType } = blocks;
    const InnerBlocks = editor.InnerBlocks;

    registerBlockType( 'dab/nest', { 
        title: 'Disruptive Nest',
        icon: 'layout',
        category: 'disruptive-blocks', 
        keywords: [ 'base', 'build', 'custom' ], 

        edit: function( props ) {
            return (
                el( 'div', {className: props.className + ' dab-full'},
                    el( 'div', {className: 'dab-content'},
                        el( InnerBlocks )
                    )
                )
            );
        },

        save: function( props ) {
            return (
                el( 'div',
                    el( 'div',
                        el( InnerBlocks.Content, null )
                    )
                )
            );
        },
    });
})( window.wp.blocks, 
    window.wp.element, 
    window.wp.blockEditor
);
```

Comment: why the `null`? and maybe try mirroring classNames in `save`

Comment: @niklas I forgot to remove the null after attempting another solution I tried that did not work. I mirrored the classes and that appears to have done the trick. Thanks! Throw it in here as an answer and I'll flag it as the correct answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this in the Block Editor Handbook ([https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-edit-save/#classname):

"This is automatically added in the save method, but not on edit" [on the topic of props.className]. That is why I didn't have the classes mirrored initially.  Reading it again led me to realize that mirroring the classNames on the "save" function isn't what fixed it, but just having the `{}` in there after each of the parent `el( 'div',`, even if you don't specify anything, is what fixed the function.

So, it works like this, and the className is automatically added to the first `el( 'div',`:

```
save: function( props ) {
    return (
       el( 'div', {},
           el( 'div', {},
               el( InnerBlocks.Content )
            )
       )
    );
},
```

Thanks, @niklas for helping me realize this.

Comment: voting comments up is a nice way to show, how others helped you

Comment: @niklas unfortunately, I'm too green to vote on comments. I only have 6 rep haha. That is why I made sure to mention you in my answer, because that is the best I can do right now. Thanks again!